# How to show images from SpringBoot Backend in Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot

I have here a Spring Boot backend, which ist storing images in MySQL DB, and a Frontend in Angular, in which I like to display images in p-table Element (PrimeNG).

Due to technological requirements (old DB structure) in the Backend data is stored in two different tables: personal data in "personal" and images in "images". I extract all Person data from DB, and then for each add an image as base64 encoded field:

```
Iterable<Person> persons = personRepository.findAll();
        for (Person p : persons) {
            Optional<ImageData> imgData = imageDataRepository.findById(p.getImageId());
            if (!imgData.isEmpty() && null != imgData.get() && null != imgData.get().getImage()) {
                p.setImageName( Base64.getEncoder().withoutPadding().encodeToString(imgData.get().getImage()));
            }

        }
```

I can see data send and filled with something seemingly base64 in field ImageName. Those are image data I would like to show in the frontend.

In Angular frontend I read all data as an Observable. Here the Service:

```
getPersonsObservable(): Observable<Person[]> {
        const url = `${this.baseUrl}/all`
        return this.http.get(url).pipe(
            map(this.extractData),
            catchError(this.handleErrorObservable)
        )
    }

    private extractData(res: any) {
        let body = res;
        return body;
    }
```

and then enhance to dbimage field:

```
this.personService.getPersonsObservable().subscribe( res => {
            res.forEach(person => {
                person.dbImage = 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + person.imageName;
                this.persons.push(person);
                
            });
            
            }
        )
```

and then try to show it in component:

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-person>
                    <tr>
                    <td>

                        <img [src]=person.dbImage />

                        </td>
```

Table fields still remain empty, no images to be shown. No error whatever to be seen in the Development console.

Any ideas?

Any ideas why images are not showing? no error whatever to seen in Chromes Console

Comment: You don't show the ts code for Person, but I'm suspicious about you using person.imageName as the content of the image.  Have you confused the name of the image and the content of the image?